# My co.za domain name won't propagate

Tags: dnssec

I bought a co.za domain name at Godaddy and changed the A record to point to Justhost. However the domain will not propagate. I checked https://dnschecker.org https://dnschecker.org. It's been over 72 hours and nothing. What must I do? Neither provider can provide answers.

Comment: DNSSEC? If you're unsure what this does, turn it off first.

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: The domain name is gapstar.co.za

Comment: DNNSEC is not enabled for gapstar.co.za. Still no propagation.